# How to divide code using functions Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got my code to work but now I need to divide it into functions input(), processing() and output().

```
lista=[]
lista = [int(clan) for clan in input("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',')]
lista.reverse()
rezultat=[]
c=0
for i in lista:
    if i < 0:
        i = i * -1
        t = i
        rev = 0
        rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
        t = t // 10
        i = i * -1
        rezultat.append(str(i))
    else:
            t = i
            rev = 0
    while t > 0:
        rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
        t = t // 10
        if rev == i:
            c=c+1
            rezultat.append(str(i))
            if c == 0:
                print("")
print(','.join(rezultat))
```

I do not really know how to do it so it would be nice if someone can help me

Comment: can you provide details what your goal is, what your trying to do and what will be output ?

Comment: Well I need to input a list as example 6556,123,181,10,-5  and fine witch numbers are palindromes and get reverse output such as -5,181,6556 and if there is no palindromes in the inputted list there should be no output, my code works but I need to use function

Comment: That question is very general... Go over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), specifically [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). Read about how functions work and try to ask a more specific question about what you're struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```py
def get_input():
    lista = [int(clan) for clan in input("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',')]
    lista.reverse()
    return lista
    
def process_input(input):
    rezultat=[]
    c=0
    for i in input:
        if i < 0:
            i = i * -1
            t = i
            rev = 0
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t // 10
            i = i * -1
            rezultat.append(str(i))
        else:
            t = i
            rev = 0
        while t > 0:
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t // 10
            if rev == i:
                c=c+1
                rezultat.append(str(i))
                if c == 0:
                    print("")
                    
        return rezultat
        
def main():
    lista = get_input()
    result = process_input(lista)
    
    def output(xlist):
        return ','.join(xlist)
    
    output(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

that should work, but I don't see the need to divide it into functions, since the code might even work well as one function.

Comment: Hi thank you very much this helped me a lot but I don't get output from this ex. I input list components 6556,123,181,10,-5 and the output should be -5,181,6556 , but I get nothing

Comment: Well the `output` function doesn't do anything... It needs to be `print(','.join(xlist))`

Comment: Yeah but what do I put in it, it has "return rezultat" in processing but it doesn't print it anywhere and if I put rezultat instead of xlist it still does nothing

Answer (score 3):

Something like this...

```
def input(clan):

    lista = [int(clan) for clan in input("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',')]
    lista.reverse()

    return lista   


def processing(lista):

    rezultat = []
    c = 0
    for i in lista:
        if i < 0:
            i = i * -1
            t = i
            rev = 0
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t // 10
            i = i * -1
            rezultat.append(str(i))
        else:
                t = i
                rev = 0
        while t > 0:
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t // 10
            if rev == i:
                c=c+1
                rezultat.append(str(i))
                if c == 0:
                    print("")
    return(','.join(rezultat))

def output(result):

    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    result_list = input(clan)
    result = processing(result_list)
    output(result)
```

Comment: updated to make more independent @sahasrara62

Answer (score 1):

Try using the def command,
like this

```
def inp(): #declare a function
    #your commands
inp() #run the commands
```

Don't forget to declare global variables a.k.a. those variable that you might alter in many functions by using the `global` command.